# Confused with What Kind of Test I Should be Using

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study

I have a question from an exam:

The chef rates the taste quality of 5 different brands of anchovies. The brands came packaged in both a jar and a can. The chef rates 10 combinations of brand/packaging from 1 to 10 (where 10 is the best taste). The following is the ratings:

```
Brand / Rating  
A (Jar) / 2  
A (Can) / 4    
B (Jar) / 1  
B (Can) / 2  
C (Jar) / 6  
C (Can) / 9  
D (Jar) / 8  
D (Can) / 10  
E (Jar) / 1  
E (Can) / 3
```

We want to test if there is evidence that the method of packing (Jar versus Can) is related to a difference between the tastiness (to the Chef) of anchovies: (1) State the Null Hypothesis, (2) State the Alternative Hypothesis, (3) Explain what test statistic you would use, compute it, and explain how you would get a p-value for it.

My approach would be to use a chi-square test by adding all the ratings from Jar and Can, respectively. Thus, my null hypothesis will be that packaging (Jar and Can) is independent of Rating (Tastiness). Is this the right approach? Or, should I use the paired t-test or a sign test since the data doesn't seem to follow a normal distribution.

Comment: A paired t-test or the non-parametric equivalent would be a good choice.

Comment: Chi-squared is not the way to go here.

Comment: This question would benefit from a more specific title, but it does seem clear and to comply with our self-study policy so I do not think it should be closed.